# SELECT multiple columns from 4 different TABLES

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, multiple-tables, multiple-select

I have 4 tables: order, order_product, product, product_description.

I am trying to get the following colomuns from these four tables:
**author**(product_description),**name**(product_description), **model**(product),**order_id**(order)
WHILE the order.order_status_id=1

I am using this query:

```
SELECT          product_description.name AS name
        product_description.author AS author
        product.model AS model
            `order`.`order_id` AS `order_id`
FROM product_description
INNER JOIN product_description ON product.product_id=product_descripton.product_id
INNER JOIN product ON `order`.product_id=product.product_id
INNER JOIN `order` ON `order_product`.`order_id`=`order`.`order_id`
WHERE `order`.`order_status_id`=1
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: How does it now work?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'product_description.author AS author product.model AS model ' at line 2

Comment: If I SELECT * i get this:
 #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'product_description'

Comment: what does you mean by 'it doesn't work'?  what are you getting?

Comment: Needs commas between the items in the select clause

Comment: See the comments above please.

Comment: It doesn't work, even if i remove the SELECT items and I just leave a star select..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the commas in the select and you joined the same table twice and you had a typo in one of the inner joins, this should work:

```
SELECT  product_description.name AS name,
        product_description.author AS author,
        product.model AS model,
        `order`.`order_id` AS `order_id`
FROM product_description
INNER JOIN product ON product_description.product_id=product.product_id
INNER JOIN order_product ON order_product.product_id=product.product_id
INNER JOIN `order` ON `order`.order_id=order_product.order_id
WHERE `order`.order_status_id=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this message: #1054 - Unknown column 'order.product_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: PS: the product table doesn't have an order_id column

Comment: I have to connet the ORDER on ORDER_PRODUCT via order_id, then the connected table on PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION via product_id, and finnaly the last table on PRODUCT via product_id

Comment: Ok I just edited my answer to take into account all of your requirements